# Windows for loop through dirs, run git pull?

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, git, cmd.exe

From Bash it's simple:

```
for d in *; do GIT_DIR="$d/.git" git pull; done
```

Or:

```
for d in *; do GIT_DIR="$PWD/$d/.git" git pull; done
```

However from Windows Command Prompt it's not quite as simple. I've tried:

```
for /D %i in (*.*) do cd "%i" && git pull
for /D %i in (*.*) do cd "<absolute_path>\%i" && git pull
for /D %i in (*.*) do set GIT_DIR="<absolute_path>\%i\.git git pull"
for /D %i in (*.*) do set GIT_DIR="<absolute_path>\%i\.git && git pull"
```

But none work. Always getting one of these errors:

```
fatal: unable to access '"repo-name/.git" /config': Invalid argument
The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: are you sure this doesn't work `c:\sdf>for /D %i in (*.*) do (CD c:\sdf\%i && DIR && pause)`   use the pause to troubleshoot.  Another variation is `c:\sdf>for /D %i in (*.*) do (CD %i && DIR && CD .. && PAUSE)`   and `c:\sdf>for /D %i in (*.*) do (PUSHD %i && DIR && POPD && PAUSE)`

Comment: if you see the FOR is doing what you want, and get it to do what you want, then you can look at the GIT command

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works for me in a batch file in CMD:

```
for /d %%i in (*.*) do cd %%i & git pull & cd..
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Replace `%%` with `%` when running purely on CMD (not in a script).

Answer (score 4):

Couldn't this be a simple one-liner in Powershell?

Example:

```
Resolve-Path D:\work\repos\*\.git | foreach { cd $_; git pull }
```

Comment: I'd prefer to use Windows Batch; is there no way to make the aforementioned `for`-loop work?

Comment: Powershell is the de facto shell on Windows. Cmd will be deprecated in the future. 

There's no use in trying to cobble something together in cmd when there's an object oriented Windows shell right at your fingertips which makes everything so much easier.

-my two cents :-)

Comment: Really? - Well alright, just change your code to `D:\work\repos\*` and I'll accept.

Comment: The Resolve-Path command as I posted it automatically gets all the folders in repos and then looks for a folder called .git in each of them. That's where you want to cd into according to your code. It's a pretty elegant solution.

If you remove the pipe and everything after it you'll see that it gives you all of the .git folders.

Answer (score 1):

Enter `powershell` into *Explorer address field* of your *base folder* and *hit enter*. Then execute:

```
Get-ChildItem . -exclude *.ps1,temp,*.txt | foreach { cd $_; Write-Host "`r`n" $_; Git pull '-v' }
```

Use this approach, if `Resolve-Path` won't work for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use `git pull <repository>` syntax instead on Git Shell with `cmd.exe` default shell setting, and look up `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` for variable initialization (`set`) inside `for` loop.